# Using for loop to insert character between elements of string

Tags: python

```
def main():
    string = raw_input("string:")
    pattern = raw_input("pattern:")
    end = len(string)
    insertPattern(string,pattern)

def insertPattern(string,pattern):
    end= len(string)-1
    print "Iterative:",
    for x in range(end):
        if x == end:
            print string[x]
        if x < end:
            print string[x]+pattern,

main()
```

I'd like this to output 
[image]
Instead it's outputting
[image]

How would I modify the code to fix this? Assignment requires that I do this without lists or join.

Comment: If you don't want it outputting the word "Iterative:" then don't print it.  If you don't want spaces between them, then use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got three problems here.

---

First, the reason you're getting that `Iterative:` at the beginning is because you explicitly asked for it with this line:

```
print "Iterative:",
```

Just take it out.

---

The reason you're getting spaces after each `*` is a bit trickier. The `print` statement's "magic comma" always prints a space. There's no way around that. So, what you have to do is not use the `print` statement's magic comma.

There are a few options:

- Use the more-powerful `print` *function* from Python 3.x, which you can borrow in 2.7 with a `__future__` statement. You can pass any separator you want to replace the space, even the empty string.
- Use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`; that way you get neither newlines nor spaces unless you write them explicitly.
- Build up the string as you go along, and then `print` the whole thing at the end.

The last one is the most general solution (and also leads to lots of other useful possibilities, like returning or storing the built-up string), so I'll show that:

```
def insertPattern(string,pattern):
    result = ''
    end= len(string)-1
    for x in range(end):
        if x == end:
            result += string[x]
        if x < end:
            result += string[x]+pattern
    print result
```

---

Finally, the extra `*` at the end is because `x == end` can never be true. `range(end)` gives you all the numbers up to, but not including `end`.

What you probably wanted was `end = len(string)`, and then `if x == end-1`.

---

But you can simplify this quite a bit. The only reason you need `x` is to get `string[x]`, and to distinguish either the first or last value from the others (so you know not to add an extra `*` either before the first or after the last). You can solve the last one with a flag, or by just treating the first one special. And then, you can just iterate over `string` itself, instead of over its indices:

```
def insertPattern(string,pattern):
    result = string[0]
    for ch in string[1:]:
        result += pattern + ch
    print result
```

And once you've done that, you may realize that this is almost identical to what the `str.join` method does, so you can just use that:

```
def insertPattern(string,pattern):
    print pattern.join(string)
```